# How can I use sevenzipsharp to asynchronously unzip a list of archives and dispose of them correctly?

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, sevenzipsharp

How can I use SevenZipSharp to asynchronously unzip a list of archives and dispose of them correctly?

Here is what I'm looking at:

```
Public Class SevenZipVB

Private Shared extractors As New List(Of SevenZipVB)

Private WithEvents _extractor As SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor


''' <summary>
''' Extracts list of archives to their current directory always overwriting
''' </summary>
''' <param name="archives">List of full path names to archives</param>
Public Shared Sub BeginExtraction(ByVal archives As List(Of String))

    For Each archive In archives
        Dim ext = New SevenZipVB(archive)
        extractors.Add(ext)
    Next

    'magically wait for all extraction to finish but allow the calling thread to continue

End Sub

Private Sub New(ByVal archive As String)
    _extractor = New SevenZip.SevenZipExtractor(archive)
    _extractor.BeginExtractArchive(Path.GetDirectoryName(archive))
End Sub

Private Sub extractfinished() Handles _extractor.ExtractionFinished
    _extractor.Dispose()
End Sub

End Class
```

I guess I'll have to add some kind of async method but I don't know what it should look like. Any ideas?

Comment: How about looking at their documentation/discussions here https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/discussions

Comment: `BeginExtractArchive` should already be async. If you want to program your own method, try using a backgroundworker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont bother, that library is no longer supported, just use the command line 7za or 7zr